# There is a lot of free space under the closed html tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have worked with html code of page: http://www.earsel.org/?target=earsel/earsel. The problem is, that there is a lot of free space (without any reason) under the ended html tag (see attached picture[image]).

Do You know why, and how to remove this white space? I have tried to add to CSS of HTML or Body Height or Min-Height to 100%, but this doesn't help.

Please could You help me?

Update: I have tested it in Opera 23 and IE 11. The content is in table. I am looking for a solution how to get the right blue bar to bottom - for example by some footer and dynamic height of the rest row of table?

Thank You very much.

Comment: the height is determined by the amount of content within it so more the content more the height however it renders perfectly on google chrome

Comment: Yeah I inherited and I have no time to create new one, So I have to work with this old rubbish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace all the "visibility: hidden;" with "display: none;" On the five div elements at the end of the page.

See this: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Your javascript code has to match, so you need to change your main.js file:

```
    visibility = 'visible';
    display = 'block'; // add this line at line # 39


    //menu[count][0].ref.visibility = 'hidden'; // line # 82 - comment out
    menu[count][0].ref.display = 'none'; // add this line at #83
```